# Integration between google calendar and my own .net website

Tags: .net, web, calendar, google-apps, icalendar

I am creating a small app to sync appointments from my google calendar to my website and back again.

I have read some of googles descriptions on how to do this but cannot seem to connect the dots.

Do any of you have any examples or advice regarding this to get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Calendar API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) include a getting started and how-to page.

> The Google Calendar API lets you develop client applications that create new events, edit or delete existing events, and search for events. This document describes how to use RESTful calling style and client libraries for various programming languages (currently Java, Python, PHP, .NET and Ruby) to access and edit Google Calendar data.